# Update a row, insert a new row if missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a [Date, Value] dataframe (cash_movement_df in code below). Where values needs to updated (summed up) for dates. If date is not present in dataframe already, then insert as new [date, value] row.

I have tried using following code, but looking for something more efficient.

```
date = transaction['date'].iat[0]
value = transaction['value'].iat[0]

mask = cash_movement_df['date']==date
if cash_movement_df.loc[mask]['value'].any(): 
    cash_movement_df.loc[mask, 'value'] += value
else: 
    cash_movement_df.loc[-1] = [date, value]
    cash_movement_df.index = cash_movement_df.index + 1
```

Sample input output:

```
cash_movement_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'], 'value': [1, 2]})
transaction = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-03'], 'value': [3]})

    date    value
2019-01-01  1.0000
2019-01-02  2.0000
2019-01-03  3.0000

transaction = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-02'], 'value': [3]})

   date     value
2019-01-01  1.0000
2019-01-02  5.0000
```

Looking for a more elegant solution. Please note cash_movement_df is large in size and transaction is 1 at a time. So, I believe a solution which makes a copy of cash_movement_df is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your transaction's data type is, I assume it is a series, if it's a dict, you can convert it to a serires.

```
import pandas as pd

cash_movement_df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02'], 'value': [1, 2]})
transaction = pd.Series({'date': '2019-01-03', 'value': 3})

# **** sthe following is your codes

# mask = cash_movement_df['date'] == transaction['date']
# if cash_movement_df.loc[mask]['value'].any():
#     cash_movement_df.loc[mask, 'value'] += transaction['value']
# else:
#     cash_movement_df.loc[-1] = [transaction['date'], transaction['value']]
#     cash_movement_df.index = cash_movement_df.index + 1
#

# **** the following is mine
transactions = transaction.to_frame().T

res = pd.merge(cash_movement_df, transactions, how='outer', on='date')
res['value_x'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
res['value_y'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
res['value'] = res['value_x'] + res['value_y']
cash_movement_df = res.drop(['value_x', 'value_y'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. 
Please note cash_movement_df is large in size and transaction is 1 at a time. So, I believe a solution which makes a copy of cash_movement_df is not efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're looking for DataFrame.add() [pandas.DataFrame.add](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add)

E.g.

```
cash_movement_df = cash_movement_df.set_index(['Date']).add(transaction.set_index(['Date']), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. 
Please note cash_movement_df is large in size and transaction is 1 at a time. So, I believe a solution which makes a copy of cash_movement_df is not efficient. Setting and resetting indices may also cause overhead?

Comment: @HDw I believe you're implying that you do not wish to perform a merge operation for every single transaction date due to your transaction data being stored as a single-line data frame. In that case, you could merge your transaction data frames into a single, large one first before merging it with cash_movement_df